# TikZ: Calculate "pre length" based on path length

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

I would like to automatically calculate the `pre length` value for a line decoration to be "centered". Let me explain it by this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[foo/.style={decorate,decoration={
    shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape sep=2.5cm,pre=moveto,pre length=#1}}]
  \node at (0cm,0cm)  [label=below:0]  {};
  \node at (5cm,0cm)  [label=below:5]  {};
  \node at (9cm,0cm)  [label=below:9]  {};
  \node at (10cm,0cm) [label=below:10] {};
  \draw[foo=0cm]    (0cm,0cm) -- (10cm,0cm); % line 1
  \draw[foo=0cm]    (0cm,5mm) -- ( 9cm,5mm); % line 2
  \draw[foo=0.75cm] (0cm,1cm) -- ( 9cm,1cm); % line 3
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*<del>(How can I add a compiled version of the code? Do I have to manually compile and upload it as a image?)</del>*

[image: compiled version]

- `line 1` (bottom) is what I want: Circles from the start of the line (0,0) to its end (10,0).
- `line 2` (middle) shows the problem: If the paths length is not a multiple of `shape sep`, the first circle is at the paths start and there is nothing between the last circle and the paths end.
- `line 3` (top) shows how the problem should be handled: By setting `pre length` to the right value (or by some other method, if you have a better idea), the distance between the paths start and the first circle is the same as the distance between the last circle and the paths end.

Now my question is: How can I set `pre length` to <del>`(path length - shape sep)/2`</del>`(path length - (number of circles - 1) * shape sep) / 2` (thanks to Altermundus for the correction)? Or is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Yes, you have to manually compile and upload as image. If you use the `standalone` documentclass the PDF will be trimmed to the size of the `tikzpicture`, and you can upload the PDF directly. (Note however that Imgur converts it to PNG, and the quality of the conversion isn't always that good, so converting yourself, or taking a screenshot, may be better.)

Comment: You can also make the decoration circles more sparse or dense depending on the path length. Would you discard that option completely?

Comment: @percusse Thanks, but then the problem would be to calculate `shape sep`. I want to use the `foo` style for multiple lines with variable lengths.

Comment: Both can be done, you need to choose as you can see from midtiby's answer :)

Comment: @percusse I choose the adjustment of `pre length`, but thanks again for your suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure of my formula but `(path length - shape sep)/2`is not very fine.  You can use some values like 
`\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength` and `\pgf@lib@shapedecoration@sep`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\begin{document} 
  \makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}%
   [foo/.style={decorate,
                decoration={shape backgrounds,
                            shape=circle,
                            shape sep=2.5cm,
                            pre=moveto,
   pre length=(\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength-%
              floor(\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength/\pgf@lib@shapedecoration@sep)*%
                     \pgf@lib@shapedecoration@sep)/2}}]
  \node at (0cm,0cm)  [label=below:0]  {};
  \node at (5cm,0cm)  [label=below:5]  {};
  \node at (9cm,0cm)  [label=below:9]  {};
  \node at (10cm,0cm) [label=below:10] {};
  \draw[foo] (0cm,1cm) -- ( 9cm,1cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Of course your formula is right, I forgot to include the number of shapes, silly me… :-P

Answer (score 9):

Some time ago I made the illustration below that places evenly spaced lipid molecules along a path.

The central part is the access to \pgfdecoratedpathlength from which the distance between neighbouring molecules is calculated.

[image: custom path decoration that adjusts to the given path]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

% Define decoration
\pgfdeclaredecoration{lipidleaflet}{initial}
{
  % Place as many segments as possible along the path to decorate
  % the minimum distance between two segments is set to 7 pt.
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength/floor(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/7pt)]
  {
    % Draw the two acyl chains
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-1pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-1pt}{-10pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-10pt}}
    % Draw the head group
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}{2.5pt}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

% Draw a vesicle composed of two lipid layers
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Micelle
\draw[decorate, decoration={lipidleaflet, mirror}] (0, 3) circle (0.6cm);
\draw (0, 2) node {Micelle};

% Inverted micelle
\draw[decorate, decoration={lipidleaflet}] (0, 0) circle (0.45cm);
\draw (0, -1) node {Inverted micelle};

% Lipid bilayer
\draw[decorate, decoration={lipidleaflet, mirror}]
  (-1, -2.8) -- (2, -2.8);
\draw[decorate, decoration={lipidleaflet}]
  (-1, -2) -- (2, -2);
\draw (0, -3.5) node {Lipid bilayer};

% Vesicle
\draw[decorate, decoration={lipidleaflet}] (5, 0.5) circle (2.5cm);
\draw[decorate, decoration={lipidleaflet, mirror}] (5, 0.5) circle (3.3cm);
\draw (5, -3.5) node {Vesicle};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks very impressive, pointed me in the right direction and is for sure helpful to others - thanks!